# Make Module global available in Angular application

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have the following Module which components I use on other modules:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';  
import { ClickOutsideModule } from "ng-click-outside";

import { PopupComponent} from './popup.component';

@NgModule({  
  declarations: [
    PopupComponent
  ],      
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ClickOutsideModule
  ],  
  exports: [
    PopupComponent
  ],
  providers: []
})

export class PopupModule {}
```

And I have my AppModule:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppBrowserModule } from './app-browser.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { HomeModule } from './home/home.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppBrowserModule,  
    HomeModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

1. Is it possible to have ClickOutsideModule available in all App modules, such as PopupModule, without the need to import it in every module?

   Or do I always need to import it in each module it uses it?
2. What is Exports in AppModule for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a `SharedModule`, add the `ClickOutsideModule` to the `imports` and `exports` array of it. Something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ClickOutsideModule } from "ng-click-outside";

@NgModule({ 
  imports: [
    ClickOutsideModule,
    ...
  ],  
  exports: [
    ClickOutsideModule,
    ...
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And then import the `SharedModule` whereever you want to have access to the `ClickOutsideModule` module. Say for eg, if you want it in the AppModule, here's how you'll do it:

```
...
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})

export class AppModule { }
```

You can do the same for `PopupModule`:

```
...
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

@NgModule({
  ...,
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ...
  ],
  ...
})

export class PopupModule { }
```